# Keras CNN doesn`t learn to predict bounding boxes

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm working on a CNN in keras to get the bounding boxes of skirts worn by models in pictures. As i know that each picture contains (exactly) one skirt worn by a model i assumed,that i could just add some dense layers on top of a pretrained model (i tried VGG16 and ResNet) and train it to get 4 outputs. 
However the loss function remains pretty much the same each epoch (for training and validation data) and when i want to predict bounding boxes with the model I get boxes that are pretty much [0,0,0,0] (pretty much meaning that the values are very small, like 1e-7). 
I allready tried changing the optimizer, learningrate etc. But nothing seems to work.

I suspect that my approach simlpy is way to easy and naive and i have to look at more complex ways of localization like Faster-RCNN but that type of complexity exceeds not only my capability(by far as you can see) but also the purpose of the network. So I hoped maybe you could help me out here.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Code:
Setting up the model:

```
def getModel_Segmentation(input_shape=(300,300,3),border_mode='same',activation='relu',retrain_layers=0,neurons_dense_layer=4096):

    model=VGG16(weights="imagenet",include_top=False,input_shape=input_shape)
    for i in range(len(model.layers) - retrain_layers):
        model.layers[i].trainable=False

    x=Flatten()(model.output)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
    x = Activation(activation)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = Dense(4, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

    return Model([model.input],x)
```

Compiling it:

```
def l2loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_true,y_pred))))

model=generateModel_Segementation()
model.compile(loss=l2loss,optimizer=SGD(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Getting the Data, this is where i think i am wrong if i am:
(I have csv files that contain picturename.jpg;x0;y0;x1;y1 and i know where the pictures are saved)

```
def preprocess(img):
    VGG_MEAN = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
    out = np.copy(img) * 255
    out = out[:, :, [2,1,0]] # swap channel from RGB to BGR
    out[:,:,0] -= VGG_MEAN[0]
    out[:,:,1] -= VGG_MEAN[1]
    out[:,:,2] -= VGG_MEAN[2]
    return out

x_pictures=[]
x_segments=[]
f=open(training_picture_labels)
fr=csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
for i in fr:
    try:
        img=load_img(training_picture_path+"/"+i[0])
        x_segments.append(np.array([i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4]]))
        x=img_to_array(img)
        x=preprocess(x)
        x_pictures.append(x)
    except:
        pass
traingen=ImageDataGenerator(fill_mode="constant")
#same with y_pictures and y_segments for validation data
```

Training the Model:

```
model.fit_generator(traingen.flow(x=np.array(x_pictures), 
    y=np.array(x_segments),
    batch_size=64),validation_data=valgen.flow(x=np.array(y_pictures), 
    y=np.array(y_segments)),epochs=50,steps_per_epoch=50,verbose=1)
```

Comment: What's the range of your bounding box coordinates? Softmax does not look right for this purpose.

Comment: I thought about that too. I allready tried dividing all coordinates by 1000 so they are between 0 and 1, but didn't work either

Comment: It won't work with softmax, it might work with sigmoid at the output. In any case how you normalize box coordinates matters a lot.

Comment: Ok, then i will try sig. Would rescaling the coordinates be enough normalization?

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Works way better now